# In Troll 2 why does Arnold morph into a tree, but the girl becomes a green slime?

Tags: troll-2

In the scene where the witch Creedence offers the poison to both, the girl turns into a green slime and Arnold into a tree.

Why?
Isn't the poison supposed to turn everyone into the green slime the trolls eat?

Comment: I think the tree is a form of storage, so he can be turned into slime and eaten later.  Dont forget the popping corn.

Comment: I know "it's just a plot hole/inconsistency/bad writing" is never an acceptable answer here, but surely, just this once, it's the *only* answer? We're talking about a film generally regarded as one of the worst ever made.

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_2) simply says that the poison turns people "into plants."  At the end of the movie the mother is something green, but not the same slime...

Comment: @rld, great idea and the reference to the popcorn, yeah!!!

Comment: @F1Krazy, yeah thats right, I only intend to clarify the idea, if possible, of course perhaps its a bad movie, but even the great plots as one or two errors over there.

Comment: @DavidW, thats why I dont understand, unless the green slime its some type of mashed  vegetable, I dont recall seeing the trolls (or whatever these were) feeding from vegetals directly, instead they eat the slime, and the end scene, I would take as the same slime since the girl in some moment has the same aspect.

Comment: By the way, perhaps is one of the worst movies ever, but that Credence is one of the most crazy and yet lovely characters, its perhaps the strong part of the movie, it is supposed to have a troll form, but I always see she as human.